# Is the initialization of data members part of constructor?

Tags: c++

As far as I know, this initialization will be complemented before the function body of the constructor.

If the initialization of data members is the part of constructor, then it should be inlined when the contructor is inlined, otherwise on the contrary.

By the way, how about the constructor list? And is the destroy of data member part of deconstructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption is wrong. Compilers may partially inline functions. It's even easier to do so for constructors and destructors as you can't take their address anyway.

Still, that's something you won't notice at C++ level, only if you inspect the assembly.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the member initialization part of the constructor for functional effects and the member destruction part of the destructor. But what is inlined and what is invoked is not guaranteed. This part is depends totally on the compiler you are using.